# Outputting dictionary values to a csv + removing specific characters

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
scores = {'Tom': [9, 8], 'Alice': [10, 10], 'Ben': [10, 9]}
```

I am outputting these scores to the csv file in the following way:

```
file = open("test.csv","w")
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n")
for item in scores.items():
    writer.writerow(item)
```

This creates a csv file that looks like this:

```
Tom, [9, 8]
Alice, [10, 10]
Ben, [10, 9]
```

How can I remove the brackets and comma so I am left with just the numbers? - [ , ]

I would like to create a csv file that looks like this:

```
Tom, 9 8
Alice, 10 10
Ben, 10 9
```

Comment: did you want the output to be in order?

Comment: For future reference, if you say "How can I remove the brackets and comma", but you actually don't want to remove the comma, you're going to get answers that do what you asked for, not what you actually want.  Posting a concrete example of desired output helps remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delimiter is set to `delimiter=','` so that is what you are going to get. If you want different delimiters you may as well just use the a normal file.write but having different delimiters is not going to help when you decide to read the contents again.

```
for k,v  in scores.items():
    writer.writerow([k]+ v)
```

Output:

```
Tom,9,8
Ben,10,9
Alice,10,10
```

If you really want to mix both you can add a comma to the key but if I were you I would pick one delimiter:

```
with  open("test.csv","w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ', lineterminator="\n")
    for k,v  in scores.items():
        writer.writerow([k+","]+ v)
```

Comment: *can I remove the brackets **and comma***

Comment: @Kasra, `delimiter=','`